# Getting error Unsupported Grant type?

Tags: ios, post, oauth, swift3, alamofire

I am not able to login in my Application which uses Oath-2 and getting error of unsupported_grant_type.I am using Alamofire to POST login data but not able to succeed.Where i am doing Wrong ?I am not able to solve the issue.

func sendFeedback()

```
func sendFeedback(){


        let parameters = [

            "UserName": username_textfield.text! as String,
            "Password": password_textfield.text! as String,
            "grant_type": "Password" as String,
                    ]


        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
            }}, to: "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],
                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.response { [weak self] response in
                            guard self != nil else {
                                return
                            }
                            debugPrint(response)
//                            self?.view.hideToastActivity()
                            self?.view.makeToast(message: "Send Successfull. !!!")

                        }
                        upload.uploadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "uploadQueue"), closure: { (progress) in


                        })
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print("errorss:\(encodingError)")
                    }
        })

    }
```

I am getting status code of 400.How this issue be Solved?

Comment: Try "password' (Lowercase) 
RFC 6749 "This specification defines four grant types -- authorization code, implicit, resource owner .... Unless otherwise noted, all the protocol parameter names and values are case sensitive"

Comment: its not working on changing the password to lowercase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Try this**,this may help you

```
let headers = [
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       ]
       let parameters = [

           "UserName": username_textfield.text! as String,
           "Password": password_textfield.text! as String,
           "grant_type": "password",
                   ]
       //        let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token")!
       Alamofire.request("http://192.168.100.5:84/Token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:  URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

           switch(response.result) {

           case .success(_):
               if response.result.value != nil{
//                    print(response.result.value ?? )
                   let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                   print("...HTTP code: \(statusCode)")
               }
               break

           case .failure(_):
//                print(response.result.error ?? )
               break

           }
       }
```

Comment: @BikeshThakur :-)